# How to connect to Mobile Broadband with Google Fi SIM card

Tags: networking, 18.04, google, mobile-broadband

In Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a Lenovo Thinkpad T480s, I just plugged in a Google Fi SIM Card, and it's not connecting. After setting the APN name to "h2g2", as explained [here](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6330195?hl=en), I get a "Activation of network connection failed" message.

Any ideas on what I could be wrong? Thanks in advance.